# Why I am getting Type error when fetch URL from Swiggy restaurant

Tags: reactjs

Why I am getting Type error when fetch URL from Swiggy restaurant

```
async function getRequest() {
    fetch('https://www.swiggy.com/restaurants/meghana-foods-5th-block-koramangala-bangalore-229')
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => console.log(data.response.docs))
    .catch( e => console.log(e))
}
getRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are fetching from returns HTML, not JSON, so `res.json()` will fail. Perhaps you meant to call the [Swiggy API?](https://apitracker.io/a/swiggy)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to call Swiggy API. But it's not showing in the console. Can you please help me what I need to change in the code?

Comment: You would need to change the URL to point to a Swiggy API endpoint (which would return JSON) instead of the Swiggy webpage (which returns HTML)

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please explain with the code?

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between HTML and JSON, and between an API and a regular webpage. The URL you are fetching from (https://www.swiggy.com/restaurants/meghana-foods-5th-block-koramangala-bangalore-229) returns HTML, so you cannot call `.json()` on its result. That's why your request fails. I'm not sure if Swiggy has a public API that you can call, otherwise you could try to perform some web scraping to get the data you require from the page into your application.

Answer (score 0):

See dear you are calling **fetch('https://www.swiggy.com/restaurants/meghana-foods-5th-block-koramangala-bangalore-229')** -> this is the url of a webpage which returns an html document so we cannot call **res.json()** over it. If you want to fetch restaurants from swiggy you can use this one :

**fetch('https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/restaurants/list/v5?lat=23.1685786&lng=79.9338798&is-seo-homepage-enabled=true&page_type=DESKTOP_WEB_LISTING')**

If you want to get data of particular restaurant you can use this api :

**fetch('https://www.swiggy.com/dapi/menu/pl?page-type=REGULAR_MENU&complete-menu=true&lat=23.1685786&lng=79.9338798&restaurantId=158376')**

replace ***lat*** , ***lng*** and ***rastaurantId*** according to your area.
you can find it very easily on swiggy ->

- go to swiggy website open developer tools.
- go to fetch/xhr
- and try to find this fetch call shown in the image below:
  [go to the url if not able to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr6dG.png)

---

Now you can call res.json() on the respnse of this api.

Remainder: You can get cors policy error if you are not using any cors extension.

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting a Type error when trying to fetch the URL from Swiggy restaurant is because the `fetch` function is used to make HTTP requests, but the URL you are trying to fetch is not returning JSON data. The `.json()` method is used to parse the response as JSON, so if the response is not in JSON format, it will result in a Type error.

To resolve this issue, you can try using the `.text()` method instead of `.json()` to retrieve the response as text data. Here is an updated version of your code:

```js
async function getRequest() {
    fetch('https://www.swiggy.com/restaurants/meghana-foods-5th-block-koramangala-bangalore-229')
    .then( res => res.text())
    .then( data => console.log(data))
    .catch( e => console.log(e))
}
getRequest();
```

This will fetch the response as text data instead of JSON, which should help resolve the Type error you are encountering.

Comment: "so res.json() will fail. use res.json()." so you recommend what will fail? I do not get your answer. Please [edit] according to [answer] andmake sure that the solution is directly here, not only linked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).